# Angular Chart does not update on data change

Tags: angularjs, angular-chart

I have an [Angular Chart](http://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/) bar which is supposed to be updated on an ng-click event that retrieves JSON data from a servlet. The problem is that even though data is updated on the $scope the chart does not reflect the update. Why is this happening? Is there a way to redraw the chart manually? I couldn't find much documentation on Angular Chart website.

EDIT: As requested I also attached the template, can it be related to the fact that I have the same controller on two different divs?

```
    <div class="row" ng-controller="mygraphcontroller as chart">
        <!-- other things -->
        <a ng-click="applyFilterGraph()" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-raised">Apply</a>
        <!-- other things -->
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12" ng-controller="mygraphcontroller as chart">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading">*****</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <canvas id="bar" class="chart chart-bar" data="data" labels="labels"></canvas>   
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

app.controller('mygraphcontroller', ['$scope', '$http', '$log', function($scope,$http,$log) {

    $scope.labels = [];
    $scope.data = [];

    // THE FOLLOWING POST WORKS FINE ON RUNTIME

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/myservlet', 
        params: { param1: 'param1' }
    }).success(function(result) {

        var slabels = [];
        var array = [];
        var sdata = [array];

        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            slabels.push(result[i].company.companyDescription);
            array.push(result[i].value);
        }

        $scope.labels.push.apply($scope.labels,slabels);
        $scope.data.push.apply($scope.data,sdata);

    }).error(function(result) {
    });

    // THIS ONE DOES NOT WORK, CHART IS NOT UPDATED

   $scope.applyFilterGraph = function() {

        $scope.labels = [];
        $scope.data = [];


        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: '/myservlet', 
            params: { param2: 'param2' }
        }).success(function(result) {

        var slabels = [];
        var array = [];
        var sdata = [array];

        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            slabels.push(result[i].company.companyDescription);
            array.push(result[i].value);
        }

        $scope.labels.push.apply($scope.labels,slabels);
        $scope.data.push.apply($scope.data,sdata);

        }).error(function(result) {
        });

    };
```

Comment: Show the template, I have the impression that the variable is in a sub scope and is not been notified of the model change

Comment: @Raulucco here you go!

Comment: No, I just renamed it while copy-pasting it on Stackvoerflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like it's either a naming issue or the way your controller is bound to the template

Try changing `ng-controller="mygraphcontroller chart"` to `ng-controller="mygraphcontroller"`

You're also binding it to two different divs, try binding it to one that covers the whole file, a top level div that is set to `ng-controller="mygraphcontroller"`

Comment: Looks like you were right, moving everything in a single div solved the problem, thank you.